# XMLHTTPRequest size limit

Tags: jquery, web-services, networking, web-applications

does anyone know if there's a limit to the size of an XMLHTTPRequest object that can be transmitted over the network?  I have and issue where I'm making a GET request to retrieve a JSON object from the server using jquery's $.ajax call.  The problem is that when the object is larger than a few megabytes, I get back the error:

```
"NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101"
"Error: A network error occurred in synchronous requests.
 at Object.jQuery.ajaxTransport.send (/js/jquery-1.7.2.js:8240:10)
 at Function.jQuery.extend.ajax (/js/jquery-1.7.2.js:7719:15)"
```

In my testing, the largest object I'm able to get back was about 3.88MB.  My server is running PHP on Windows Server 2008 with IIS 7.0.  Is there some hard limit that can be configured on my server?  Or is this issue independent of the server configuration?  The PHP error log on the server doesn't show any issues creating the object, it gets constructed and returned to the client.  This is not reproducible on my local dev environment, which leads me to believe there must be some hard limit I'm hitting when transmitting the object over the network.  Any insight is appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

JQuery Doesn't have any limit on the size of the json object you receive. The issue would be typically caused from the server side due to the delay in responding due to the size of the object or the processing of the huge amount of data.

Please check your server's memory limit, execution time limit to check where the error occurs.  I have used JQuery to work with MB's of data and experienced the problem with teh server memory limit and once i increase the server memory limit for script execution, it worked without any problems.

Hope this helps.